# Regular Expression to match everything but the first two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Regular Expression that matches everything after the first two characters in a string.

For Example (original string listed first, then what I'd like to match):

```
AZ0bc1234  > 0bc1234
50def123   > def123
!@hijk1234 > hijk1234
```

All that matters is position, any characters (alpha-numeric with symbols) could be included in the original string.

I've tried many things, but everything I attempt matches at least one of the first two characters. The closest I've come is using `\B.*` to match everything but the first character.

Comment: I'll have a proper look at it, but in the meantime you might find this link useful www.regexlib.com

Comment: What language are you using?  Are you sure you need to use a regex?  If you're using PHP, for example, you could use the `substr()` function.

Comment: I understand there are easier ways of doing this, but I'm curious if it's theoretically possible using regular expressions exclusively.

Comment: you need to specify the language you are using

Comment: I'm attempting this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want everything but the first two characters, you could try this (to capture up to the end of each line):

```
".{2}(.*)$"
```

You are after the first group (in parens). Or differently:

```
"(?:.{2})(.*)$"
```

Comment: @Aphelion group is required here..you cant use `lookbehind` in `javascript`

Comment: Since lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript, it seems it's not actually possible to match everything after the first two characters. So, @Some1.Kill.The.DJ is right, using groups is required, and a non-capture group `(?:.{2})(.*)$` is probably the best way to go about this. Using other languages, @Aphelion's solution `(?<=.{2})(.*)$` would likely work best. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You were looking for a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). this will *only* match the part you've requested.

```
(?<=.{2})(.*)$
```

---

You've updated your question and wrote that you use JavaScript. Lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript. However I will leave this answer for future search results.

Comment: lookbehind not supported in javascript

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Ah. That was not stated in the question initially. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following will hold the matching string in the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (define by the parenthesis) :

```
^.{2}(.+)
```

You should be able to use it with `$1` or `\1` depending on the language.